# Writing a custom post type pagination plugin

Tags: jquery, wordpress, pagination, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type on my WordPress website and these posts are displayed on three different pages on my site.

My posts are sorted by two conditions and both conditions are displayed on one page, just one of the conditions on the next page, and the other on the third page. When I click on one of the posts, I need pagination at the top of the post that only goes through the posts that were on the page that I came from.

Is there any way to do this? My original thought was to get my referring page, get the URLs from my posts on that page, and then go to the previous/next one. But then if I try to get the referring page from that post, I'll get my first post and I won't get my URLs. Could I send the URLs along from my listings page to the post and in turn send them to my next post?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Here's some code I've already tried:

```
$(function(){
    $(".single_vehicle_previous_button").click(function(){
        var referrer = document.referrer;
            if (document.referrer == "http://localhost/sr19repairables/vehicles/repairables/") {
                $.ajax(document.referrer)
                    .done(function(html) { 
                        var urls = $("<div/>").html(html)
                                    .find("a")
                                    .map(function(i, e) { return $(this).attr("href");});
                                        $arr = (urls);
                                        function getClosest($search, $arr) {
                                            return $arr[array_search($search, $arr)+1];
                                        }

                    });
            }
            else{
                $('.single_vehicle_previous_button').hide();
            }
    });
});
```

Comment: What do you mean with "just one of the conditions on the next page, and the other on the third page"? An example of what you're trying to achieve would help understand the issue better. Also, if you have code for this in place please share it as well.

Comment: @cabrerahector Check out my [website](https://www.sr19repaiarables.com/vehicles/) to see what I'm trying to do. I've tried some code, check my edit

Comment: @cabrerahector Sorry, I misspelled my website. Try [this link](https://www.sr19repairables.com/vehicles/).

Comment: So, you mean how to paginate your custom post type (cars) while maintaining the current filters (make and model)?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I also need to maintain the condition (rebuilt and repairable)